# In Azure DevOps, how do we access build artifacts and the build environment itself in future container job steps?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to have a pipleline that does a maven build and then have a later step in the pipeline that uses a docker container to do some operation on the built artifact(s).

This page explains how to run a script in the context of a Docker container - great:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

What I'm not seeing is documentation on how to access, from the Docker container, artifacts from previous build steps, or for that matter, the build environment itself.

GitLab, for example, allows you to share artifacts between steps and exposes a whole slew of environment information to container jobs.  How is this accomplished in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Publish build artifacts. Consume the artifacts in a later step and copy them into the container.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Am hoping to not have to leave the build system (i.e. not publish and then pull from an external repo).  In any event, can you point to any Azure DevOps docs that illustrate what you describe?

Comment: Think I found it here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml